# Why did removing a set of parenthesis from my answer to leetcode question 704. Binary Search fix my problem

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search

I had something like this code

```
class Solution {
public:
    int search(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        int lower = 0;
        int upper = nums.size()-1;
        while(lower <= upper){
            int avr = (lower + (upper - lower))/2;
            if (nums[avr] < target ){
                lower = avr + 1;
            }else if (nums[avr] > target){
                upper = avr - 1 ;
            }else {
                return avr;
            }
        }
        return -1;

    }
};
```

I kept running it and it kept telling me it was too slow

Finally through removing and changing random lines I changed the code on line 8 from

```
 int mid = (low + (high - low))/2;
```

to

```
 int mid = low + (high - low)/2;
```

I simply removed one set of parenthesis and all of a sudden the code works like a charm and my submission was accepted.
Anyone have an explanation about why this is the case?

I tried Googling to find out why it doesn't work but in all honesty I don't even know where to start googling.

Comment: The first version divides `low + (high - low)` by 2; the second only divides `high - low` by 2, then adds that to `low`.

Comment: The two expressions have entirely different meanings. Why do you feel they are interchangeable? They produce different values.

Comment: The 2 results are not the same. In the first one, i.e., `int mid = (low + (high - low))/2;`, it simplifies to `int mid = high/2;`, while the second one is basically the same as `int mid = (high + low)/2;`.

Comment: See [C++ Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). `/` has a higher precendence than `+`, so in `low + (high - low)/2`, the `/2` is applied only to `(high - low)`, then the result is added to `low`.

Comment: If only you had used a debugger, It would have told you very quickly that the two expressions are not the same.

Comment: BTW: [std::lower_bound](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) exists in the standard library, there is no reason to reinvent binary search (except for learning its concept).

Comment: *Finally through removing and changing random lines...* -- Programmers do not work this way.  You should have debugged your code, not change "random lines".  When there is an issue with what a program produces, the first thing that is done is to debug the code.  It's too bad sites like Leetcode do not emphasize this basic task that *all* programmers must do.

Comment: *"Anyone have an explanation about why this is the case?"* -- Because your original code was wrong, and your fixed code was right. Where's the mystery? Bugs get fixed all the time without someone wondering how changing the code could possibly fix a bug. *You might be curious why your bug manifested as "too slow", but that would be a different question, and stepping through your code with a debugger should provide insight on that.*

Answer (score 1):

First, if you are not familiar with algebraic order of operations with regards to parentheses, read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations . All modern programming languages follow these ordering rules.

Let's say you want to find the midpoint between 75 and 125. Intuitively, you know the mid will be at 100.

**Algebraically** for `mid = (low + (high - low))/2;`

```
mid = (75 + (125-75)) / 2
mid = (75 + 50) / 2
mid = 125/2
mid = 62
```

Oops, that's not right.

Algebraically for `low + (high - low)/2`

```
mid = (75 + (125-75)/2)
mid = 75 + 50/2
mid = 75 + 25
mid = 100
```

That's better.

Another viable way to compute the midpoint is simply: `(low + high)/2`. That's a mathematically equivalent expression to `low + (high - low)/2`

```
mid = (low+high)/2
mid = (75 + 125)/2
mid = 200/2
mid = 100
```

Answer (score 1):

`int mid = (low + (high - low))/2` would, if presented like "normal" math, be

```
      low + high - low      high
mid = ----------------  =>  ----
             2                2
```

while `int mid = low + (high - low)/2` is the same as

```
            high - low      high + low
mid = low + ----------  =>  ----------
                2               2
```

The first is clearly wrong since it just divides `high` with 2.
The second results in the midpoint between `low` and `high`.

[Operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) works mostly like in normal math so in `low + (high - low) / 2` the division by `2` is done on the result of `(high - low)`. In the first formula you used parentheses to instead divide the result of `(low + (high - low))` by `2`.

Comment: yup I do not for the life of me know how I couldn't figure that out by myself.

Comment: @ShoeL4ce Pehaps you were staring at the problem for too long? That happens to everyone. I usually take a nap to get out of the "lock".